# Refresh a part of page using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page that part of this html is in it.i want user with ajax call my code then in my code session will be update then i want this table be update with jquery.i do all of them except update table with jquery.how can i do that???????????

```
    <table>
<tr>
<td>Space</td>
<td>@Html.TextBox("BenchSpace", "", new { maxlength = 20, style = "width:80px;" })</td>
<table id="tblBench">
        <tr >
            <th >space</th>
            <th ></th>
         </tr>
            @if (Session["BenchList"] != null)
             {
                var BenchList= Session["BenchList"] as List<Common.Mines.Entities.Bench>;
                  foreach (var b in BenchList)
                   {
                      <tr class='tRow'>
                          <td class='tbody'>@b.BenchSpace </td>
                          <td class='tbody'><a href='#' title='Del' ></a>  </td>
                      </tr>
                     }
                  }
           </table>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>
            <a href="#" id="InsertBench" class="insertBtn">Add</a>
           </td>
        </tr>
</table>
      $(document).on('click', "#InsertBench", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var url = '@Url.Action("SetBenchList")';
          var BenchSpace = ($.trim($('#BenchSpace').val()));
          $.post(url, { BenchSpace: BenchSpace }, function (data) {
                  if (data == "True") {
                    //how to update tblBench
                  }
              });
      });
```

//controller

```
  public bool SetBenchList(decimal BenchSpace, bool ActionType)
        {
            var BenchList = new List<Common.Mines.Entities.Bench>();

            if (Session["BenchList"] != null)
                BenchList = Session["BenchList"] as List<Common.Mines.Entities.Bench>;

                BenchList.Add(new Common.Mines.Entities.Bench() { BenchSpace = BenchSpace });

                Session["BenchList"] = BenchList;
                return true;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use the partial view.

For example:

```
public PartialViewResult SetBenchList(decimal BenchSpace, bool ActionType)
        {
            var BenchList = new List<Common.Mines.Entities.Bench>();

            if (Session["BenchList"] != null)
             {
                BenchList = Session["BenchList"] as List<Common.Mines.Entities.Bench>;

                BenchList.Add(new Common.Mines.Entities.Bench() { BenchSpace = BenchSpace });

                Session["BenchList"] = BenchList;

            }
            return PartialView();
      }
```

Your partial view:

```
@if (Session["BenchList"] != null)
             {
                var BenchList= Session["BenchList"] as List<Common.Mines.Entities.Bench>;
                  foreach (var b in BenchList)
                   {
                      <tr class='tRow'>
                          <td class='tbody'>@b.BenchSpace </td>
                          <td class='tbody'><a href='#' title='Del' ></a>  </td>
                      </tr>
                     }
                  }
$(document).on('click', "#InsertBench", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var url = '@Url.Action("SetBenchList")';
          var BenchSpace = ($.trim($('#BenchSpace').val()));
          $.post(url, { BenchSpace: BenchSpace }, function (data) {
                    //Update the data
                    $("table).html(data);
                  });
      });
```

Thanks

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to create an ajax request, and then update the table's content by that new data.

You can start by this

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'the_page's_url.cshtml'
  success: function (data) {
   $('#tableid').html(data);
  }
});
```

Now the data that is sent back by the ajax request would be written inside the table. You need to make sure that the table content would be OK.

Comment: I dont have any Data.my session is updated.i use: $('#tableid').html(); it doesnt work

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean to tell you. What I mean is that the `data` is the response by the server i.e `Response.Write("String");` then data would have `String` in it. That's what data would do here, it has nothing to do with Data or sessions here...